# How to hide a button in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know how I can make the "Next" button hidden until one of the choices are chosen. I'm open to using Javascript and JQuery.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/547fx/

Here is the Javascript:

```
function tryToMakeLink() {
//get all selected radios
var q1 = document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked');

//make sure the user has selected all 3
if (q1 == null) {
    document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button  
disabled=disabled value=Next>";
} else {
    //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
    q1 = q1.value;

    //now check the values to display a different link for the desired configuration
    if (q1 == "AT&T") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://google.com/';\">att 8gb black</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "Other") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';\">other 8b white</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "Unlocked") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://wepriceit.webs.com/';\">red</input>";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display: none` to the style of the button.  This will work with the rest of your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/547fx/1/

I would also recommend you refactor a bit and not use `innerHTML` or `onClick`.  With jQuery you can do something like:

```
$("[name=q1]").on("click", function () {
    $("#linkDiv").show();
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        //update target URL and text
    }
});
```

Comment: Or you could simply "disable" it - for usabilty reasons I think this would be better, when the user is expecting to continue something after the button is enabled, instead of beeing surprised, that something "unexpected" happened. But that is also a matter of taste.

Comment: @Lilith2k3 perhaps; it's already disabled too so he wouldn't even have to add the `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

Add this jQuery

```
$('#quiz').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
  $('#linkDiv').show();
});
```

and this CSS

```
#linkDiv {display:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r9sJS/